# Foreach Statement acting weird?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am creating a validation class in PHP. I want to validate two items in one array, and for some reason it only validates the first item. I call it like this:

```
Form::validate(array('user' => 'required', 'pass' => 'required'), 'login');
```

and the function is

```
public static function validate($rules, $form)
{
    foreach ($rules as $rule => $val) {
        if ($val === 'required') {
            if (empty($_POST[$rule])) {
                if (isset($_POST[$form])) {
                    self::$_error = Error::set('All fields are required. ' . $rule);
                    echo self::$_error;
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how I could validate both items in the one array?

Comment: Return will do just that, return, exiting the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `return true` to the end so that it will run only if everything was valid.

```
foreach (...) {
    if (...) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. Will accept your answer in 10 minutes.